# Using "ddclient" with a custom URL (php-Script on my Server)

Tags: url, dyndns

Is it possible to use ddclient on a raspberry pi for updating a *custom* host? 
I use a own PowerDNS-Server that is being updated by a URL:

`https://domain.tld/index.php?domain=<domain>&ipaddr=<ipaddr>&passwd=<pass>&ip6addr=<ip6addr>`

When I try to configure ddclient I'm not quite able to implement this unique URL. I am only able to set the basic parameters:

```
protocol=dyndns2
usev6=if, if=eth0
if-skip=Scope:Link
ssl=yes
server=server.tld
login=username
password=topsecret
domain.tld
```

Obviously, this is not working with my URL.

Might it work if I change my variables in my URL to a ddclient compliant? From `domain` to `host`, e.g.?

What other ideas are there to make that work? I just need that link to being accessed by ddclient.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use script option in `ddclient.conf` file specifying the script (the part between the server and `domain=<domain>&ipaddr=<ipaddr>&passwd=<pass>&ip6addr=<ip6addr>`)

`script=/index.php`

Hope this helps